# Bootstrap Column Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying create a bootstrap version of this: https://jsfiddle.net/yxmehwwp/

However I bump to some issues as the columns doesn't get the format like the one I sent above.

I am currently working here: https://jsfiddle.net/2w47vqff/

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

  <header class="main-header" id="header">

  <div class="col-lg-2">
     <h1 class="name"><a href="#">MY DESIGN</a></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Rode</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</header>

  </div>


<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-12 center">
      <div class="banner">
        <h1 class="headline">WELCOME</h1>
        <span class="tagline">YOu are Here</span>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>



<section>
  <h2>How</h2>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

</div>

</section>



<section class="about">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-12 center">
  <h2 class="white">Contact</h2>
</div>


   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitaHELLOta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
        voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
    </div>

  </div>



</section>



<footer class="main-footer">
<div class="col-lg-12 center">
  <div class="footer-inner">
    <span>&copy; 2067</span>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>

</div>
```

It must look exactly like the one here: https://jsfiddle.net/yxmehwwp/ but using bootstrap.

Any idea? Please help!

Comment: Are you sure your CSS file is complete?

Comment: Yep. Checkout my list

Comment: Don't expect an "exact", it looks like people are giving you the tools for you to complete the task yourself.

Comment: Hi Jon P. It may not be "exact" for as long that it helps why not. However there are some suggestion that doesn't work. That's why I am still thanking them even if their answer is not the solution to problem. Is there any issues in being polite?

Comment: Nothing wrong with being polite. However: "Your solution is not complete. See this :jsfiddle.net/yxmehwwp it must look exactly like that –" sounds more like a demand than a "thanks".

Answer (score 0):

you have written bootstrap styles for large and medium screens. Try to add the stuff for small screens also. So that you can see the same kind of results in the fiddle. For your reference I have modified a little of your code for small screens. Now you can play with this fiddle.

Instead of

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
```

Use

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2w47vqff/2/)

Comment: Your solution is not complete. See this :jsfiddle.net/yxmehwwp it must look exactly like that

Comment: I am not here to write the entire code for you. I just want to give the idea how to move forward. You need to do work on your stuff.

Comment: I understand but your solution doesn't work for me. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with `nav-justified` feature of bootstrap

Try this

Check Working [**Demo**](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/PmBwLR)

Include the following HTML and CSS.
HTML:

```
<div class="masthead">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h3 class="text-center header-title">MY DESIGN</h3>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-title {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.nav-justified {
  background-color: #000;
}

.nav-justified > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav > li > a:focus,
.nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #18bc9c;
}

.masthead {
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 0.7em;
}
```

Update:

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    .header-title {
      float: left;
    }
    nav {
      float: right;
    }
  }
```

Demo link has been updated.

Comment: Your solution is not complete. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/yxmehwwp/ it must look exactly like that.

Comment: @GaaraItachiUchiha the CSS padding, font-size and other styling you can change as per your need. The solution is basically about using the bootstrap layout..

Comment: You are correct when you said its the bootstrap layout however your solution doesn't answer my question. First of all your solution created a one column layout with just the menu. While the request is to create a logo on the left and menu on the right. Your menu is on full width.